# Figuring out an honest indicator in intrasexual selection

Tags: evolution, bioinformatics, statistics

In the first picture, the parameter $r$ seems to compare the direction and strength of two variables. In the second picture, $R^2$ seems to describe the variation of proportion of independent and dependent variables.

- With this being said, are honest indicators determined by $R^2$?
- Why is it a positive number for both graphs if we refer to the second picture? [image]

[image]

Comment: I don't understand your question. I don't know if it is a stat question or a biology question. You have t give it more thoughts and split down to the individuals elements that are unclear to you. The r values are wrong. While R^2 is always positive, R can be positive or negative. It is negative when the slope is negative, positive otherwise.

Comment: Maybe, you are trying to understand what hones signalling mean. You could have a look at [signalling theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signalling_theory) and [handicap principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handicap_principle) as a start.

Comment: It's a biology question from general bio II that includes statistics. I want to know how we can determine an honest indicator in intrasexual selection based on statistics. an honest indicator comes from Zahavis hypothesis. Its pretty clear what I'm asking....I know what it means in terms of definition i just don't know how to interpret it in graphs.

Comment: Those graphs seem to just be teaching you what r and R^2 mean; there is no relationship to honest signaling except for the headers, and the data are all synthetic.